# Ubuntu LiveCD install stuck on "creating user" step

Tags: boot, system-installation, live-cd

I've been STRUGGLING to install Ubuntu (as dual-boot with an existing Windows XP installation, on a different drive and partition) for a couple of days now.  I've already checked the md5 hash for the downloaded iso and DVD files after burning.

I have several problems that recur with my installation:

1. At first, my install would go slow as molasses, with only the
   occasional sluggish sign of activity (DVD/HD lights, etc.) before
   getting stuck at various points early in the process.  I researched
   and found that often NVidia cards are the culprit (which I have). 
   So I tried the *nomodeset* option, and that finally seemed to get
   things going (DVD/HD lights flashing regularly, progress indicator
   progressing, etc.)  But then the install *always* froze at the
   "Creating User" step.  Per another forum post, I've been trying to
   redo the process doing a "noquiet" so I can find out exactly which
   step is causing the issue, but I haven't been able to because...
2. Now when I try to either boot from the DVD or run the install
   program, I get the error messages:

   > buffer I/O error on device sr1, sector nnnn.
   >
   > ata_id[257]: HDIO_GET_IDENTITY failed for '/dev/sr1/': No message of desired type.
   >
   > (initramfs) Unable to find live file system.

   At first I thought it was due to the earlier faulty installs:  I
   went back in Windows to clear out the intended Ubuntu partitions (regular and swap).  But now I
   am wondering if this is due to the DVD drive:  it appears to freeze
   during the boot process and not respond in time.  A "noquiet"
   boot-run reveals error messages like "soft resetting link...ata slow
   to respond...forcing hard reset...etc."  As a test, one time I tried
   to eject the DVD during the process when things got stuck:  it would
   not respond until the boot process finished failing and I was forced
   to reboot.  This is all odd because this DVD drive worked fine
   previously in attempted installs, and still works fine in Windows
   XP!  And 'nomodeset' does not work for me this time.

Note that my BIOS must be one of the older ones: it has options for enabling "legacy support" for USB, but there are absolutely no menus/options for enabling boot from a USB device, so that workaround is out.

Now my friends and relatives are looking at me cross-eyed for the idea of trying Linux at all (especially since they've had easier times with their MS installs).

Comment: That error does seem to indicate a problem with either the DVD or the drive.

Comment: ...but the drive works fine in XP and worked in earlier install attempts!  I also checked all the md5 hashes (both the .iso file and the resulting DVD contents post-burn).  As far as installing, I've tried multiple options:  noquiet...nomodeset...nolapic...EDD=on (and I'm not sure what that one actually does; it was just suggested)...is there something I'm missing?  I REALLY want to avoid creating another DVD if I can help it...but is it possible to have good md5 hashes and the DVD is still bad?

Comment: So it was working at first (with the issues in point 1) but now won't boot at all from the DVD?

Comment: Correct...although I had to do some modifications to get that to work...nomodeset was the first one I tried, I believe.

Comment: Suddenly an issue with the DVD sounds like a DVD problem, even if it otherwise seems fine. Unless someone else has an idea, I'd suggest a new DVD, or at least making sure this one is free of scratches/dirt. From my experience, optical drives can be really finicky.

Comment: Tried again, with a new DVD...no luck, same results.

Comment: You can try making a USB for installing, and using a [CD to boot to the USB](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/16822/boot-from-a-usb-drive-even-if-your-bios-wont-let-you/).

Comment: Was able to start USB boot option, and it goes faster and smoother...the installer definitely has problems with my DVD drive (hope that's not the same with the OS!).  But I'm still getting stuck at the "Creating User" step--and nomodeset doesn't make a difference. I attempted an install again, with noquiet, and the command that last executed is "CRON [16285] root CMD ( [ -x /usr/lib/maxlifetime] && [ -d usr/lib/php5] && find /var/lib/php5..."  It _looks_ like commands like these were the last ones to execute, and the install has been sitting at the same point since.  Any help anyone?  THANKS!

Comment: I FOUND IT!  After much digging on the net, I found a reference to what seems to be an old bug in Ubuntu that somehow persists:  I was enabling "Encrypt my home folder," and that's what was causing the final freeze/hang at the "Creating User" step!  I unclicked this option on my next install attempt, and it ran without a hiccup...even without _nomodeset_!  I may ask a new question regarding how to encrypt one's home folder after installation, but for now I'm just exploring Linux/Ubuntu.  @Nattgew, thanks to you in particular for your suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK everyone, first things first:  if you are having consistent trouble with installing Ubuntu via DVD, I advise trying a USB installation.  My computer's BIOS did not allow USB as a boot option, so for those users in a similar boat, I would suggest the solution I found:  *[Plop](http://www.plop.at/en/bootmanager/download.html)*, a special bootmanager that you can burn to CD.  After setting your computer to look to your CDrom drive first at system startup for a bootable drive, Plop will engage and allow you to select any input interface (hard drive, USB port, CDrom, etc.) to boot from.

I did this and found I was *still* having trouble at the "Create User" step when installing Ubuntu, even from USB.  I did a bit of research, and I *think* I saw somewhere that configuring your installation settings to "encrypt your home folder" could cause issues...I'm not sure if that's due to a bug or if it's because of some users' large home-folder size.  Anyway, I disabled that option on a second attempt, and amazingly, everything worked like a charm!